# MySQL Server InnoDB posix_fallocate() error after update to 8.0.22

Tags: mysql, innodb

After I updated MySQL Server to 8.0.22 version, I get an issue with my mysqld settings and I can't start MySQL server.

Here is the error log :

```
2020-10-20T16:35:36.489961Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012128] [InnoDB] posix_fallocate(): Failed to preallocate data for file ./#innodb_temp/temp_1.ibt, desired size 81920 Operating system error number 22. Check that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded. Make sure the file system supports this function. Refer to your operating system documentation for operating system error code information
2020-10-20T16:35:36.490507Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Out of disk space.
2020-10-20T16:35:36.807468Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2020-10-20T16:35:36.808412Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-10-20T16:35:36.809642Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-10-20T16:35:36.811459Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.22)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

My OS is Debian 9.

Comment: I'd check to see if you have `apparmor` or similar security function of the OS is blocking mysqld from writing that file. Those security monitors can sometimes give misleading error messages. Cf. https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor

Answer (score 1):

I've filed a similar bug as [mysql bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102384&thanks=6&notify=3).

Basically, just like https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74167, EXT3 filesystem doesn't support posix_fallocate, and it will return [EINVAL](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_fallocate.3.html).

Comment: Please ask for clarification in the comments.